# rhel docker usage - start process at container start

Tags: docker, rhel6

so i have the following scenario to create my docker image and container. the question is: how can I have my process up at container start up ?

```
1. create image
cat /var/tmp/mod_sm.tar | docker import - mod_sm_39

2. see images
[root@sl1cdi151 etc]# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
mod_sm_39           latest              1573470bfa06        2 hours ago         271 MB
mod_site_m0305      latest              c029826a2253        4 days ago          53.8 MB
<none>              <none>              ee67b9aec2d3        4 days ago          163.4 MB
mod_site_soft       latest              0933a386d56c        6 days ago          53.8 MB
mod_site_vm151      latest              4461c32e4772        6 days ago          53.8 MB

3. create  container
docker run -it --net=host  -v /root:/root -v /usr/share/Modules:/usr/share/Modules -v /usr/libexec:/usr/libexec -v /var:/var -v /tmp:/tmp -v /bin:/bin -v /cgroup:/cgroup -v /dev:/dev -v /etc:/etc -v /home:/home -v /lib:/lib -v /lib64:/lib64 -v /sbin:/sbin -v /usr/lib64:/usr/lib64 -v /usr/bin:/usr/bin --name="mod_sm_39_c2" -d mod_sm_39 /bin/bash

4. now in container i go to my application and start the following:
[root@sl1cdi151 ven]# ./service.sh sm_start

5. check if it's up
[root@sl1cdi151 etc]# ps -ef | grep http
root        33     1  0 11:15 ?        00:00:00 ./httpd -k start -f /usr/local/clo/ven/mod_web/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
daemon      34    33  0 11:15 ?        00:00:00 ./httpd -k start -f /usr/local/clo/ven/mod_web/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
daemon      36    33  0 11:15 ?        00:00:00 ./httpd -k start -f /usr/local/clo/ven/mod_web/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
daemon      37    33  0 11:15 ?        00:00:00 ./httpd -k start -f /usr/local/clo/ven/mod_web/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
daemon      39    33  0 11:15 ?        00:00:00 ./httpd -k start -f /usr/local/clo/ven/mod_web/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
daemon      41    33  0 11:15 ?        00:00:00 ./httpd -k start -f /usr/local/clo/ven/mod_web/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
daemon      43    33  0 11:15 ?        00:00:00 ./httpd -k start -f /usr/local/clo/ven/mod_web/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
daemon      45    33  0 11:15 ?        00:00:00 ./httpd -k start -f /usr/local/clo/ven/mod_web/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
daemon      47    33  0 11:15 ?        00:00:00 ./httpd -k start -f /usr/local/clo/ven/mod_web/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
root        80     1  0 13:32 pts/2    00:00:00 grep http
```

So i need to have that up `"./service.sh sm_start"` when container is started. how can i implement that. Thank you in advance

Comment: put it at the end of your Dockerfile, either with a CMD or ENTRYPOINT

Answer (score 0):

Either specify the command as part of the `docker run` command:

```
docker run [options] mod_sm_39 /path/to/service.sh sm_start
```

or specify the command as part of the image's Dockerfile so that it will be run whenever the container is started without an explicit command:

```
# In the mod_sm_39 Dockerfile:
CMD ["/path/to/service.sh", "sm_start"]
```

Comment: where is location of docker files?

Comment: @DumitruGutu: [Wherever you put them.](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/)

Comment: Usually you create a directory and put there all your needed stuff: Dockerfile, files needed by your software that you will copy either with ADD or COPY, various scripts...

Comment: thank you guys for your quick response. let me check and test if that work for me